# Unit-testing my unit-test?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

In my unit test classes sometimes I write utility methods for something that will be used many times. Generally these are trivially simple but sometimes they are of sufficient complexity I wonder if I should actually be unit-testing the unit test!

Is this considered normal/good practice, to give a unit test class a method which tests its own internal utility method?

I'm using mstest in C# but that's probably not too relevant to the question which is higher level.

Comment: Code is tested to make sure it performs as expected. If the utilities have the potential to break then those should also be tested. don't look at it as unit testing the unit test. look at is as testing that written code works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

the point of testing is to be happy. it's a trade-off: the less tests you write, the less time you spend on writing and maintaining them but also the higher probability something will break so you will have to fix it in the middle of the night.

so if you/your team feel that your time investment in writing and maintaining those tests will pay-off, then write the tests. there is nothing strange in it. of course always try to keep tests as simple as possible to minimize the need for tests of tests